# My code will not work with my userform, why?

Tags: vba, excel

I am trying to set up a user form to do a loop and look up information in my table which is in a separate worksheet within the same workbook.

I want my user form to look up information in my table as I type and then auto fill in the other textboxes so that I can limit keystrokes and duplicates.

I found some code that worked with another user form as desired.  However, when I try to use the same code for my table it goes through the loop like it’s looking but it does not populate the user form. I have tried changing with the user forms textbox names and making sure the names match...  but to no avail.  I also have to skip over a combo box on my user form, can this effect my code?

```
Option Explicit

Dim id As String, i As String, j As Integer, flag As Boolean

Sub GetData()

If Not IsNumeric(UserForm1.TextBox1.Value) Then
  flag = False
  i = 0
  id = UserForm1.TextBox1.Value

  Do While Cells(i + 1, 1).Value <> ""
    If Cells(i + 1, 1).Value = id Then
      flag = True
      For j = 4 To 7
        UserForm1.Controls("TextBox" & j).Value = Cells(i + 1, j).Value
      Next j
    End If
    i = i + 1
  Loop

  If flag = False Then
    For j = 2 To 4
      '  UserForm1.Controls("TextBox" & j).Value = ""
    Next j
  End If

Else

End If

End Sub
```

Comment: Can you write `userform1.repaint` before the `End Sub` line?

Comment: when you launch this userform is the "separate worksheet" the active one? If not, qualify all your ranges object up to worksheet reference

Comment: why are you setting i as a string and then using it to store numbers? surely you'd dim it as a long?

Answer (score 0):

try qualifying your ranges up to worksheet reference:

```
Option Explicit

Sub GetDataA()
    Dim id As String, i As String, j As Integer, flag As Boolean

    If Not IsNumeric(UserForm1.TextBox1.Value) Then
        flag = False
        i = 0
        id = UserForm1.TextBox1.Value

        With Worksheets("myTableWorksheetName") '<--| change "myTableWorksheetName" to your actual worksheet with table name
            Do While .Cells(i + 1, 1).Value <> ""
                If .Cells(i + 1, 1).Value = id Then
                    flag = True
                    For j = 2 To 7
                        UserForm1.Controls("TextBox" & j).Value = .Cells(i + 1, j).Value
                    Next j
                End If
                i = i + 1
            Loop
        End With

        If flag = False Then
            For j = 5 To 10
                UserForm1.Controls("TextBox" & j).Value = ""
            Next j
        End If
    End If
End Sub
```

Comment: @Vicelikeelm, did you get through it?

Comment: No i have not had any luck with it yet i am still trying to get through it and I still have no clue why its not working.

Comment: step through your code (F8 to step to subsequent statement to be executed yellow highlighted) and use Immediate Window (CTRL+G) to query relevant variables value (e.g. while inside the loop you may type `?.Cells(i + 1, 1).Value` and press return to see the outcome